# Remove trailing commas from invalid json (to make it valid)

Tags: text-processing, json

Let's say I have a file as below

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
}
```

I want to remove the comma at the end of the line, if and only if the next line contains "}". So, the output will be :

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple"
}
```

However, if the file is as below. I do not want to do any change. Since the `,`s are not followed by a `}`

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

Anything with sed would be fantastic.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what fruit has to do with it. Are you saying that if you have the line `"colour": "Red"`, followed by `}`, then to leave it alone?

Comment: Thanks for the question. All I am saying is, if the pattern fruit occurs and the immediate next line does not contain "}" (close parenthesis) I do not want to remove the comma at the end of the line where the pattern "fruit" exists. However, if "}" is present in the line immediately following the line where the pattern "fruit" exists, I want to remove the comma at the end of that line (where the pattern fruit is present). Let me know if you still have question.

Comment: This is an x-y problem.  I'm fairly certain you are not concerned with the fruit value at all, you are concerned with making valid json objects.

Comment: Same question. You just repeated your self. So I am thinking that you don't want valid JSON, if the line with color has a comma at the end, even though the next line is a `}`.

Comment: I am just concerned with the"fruit" pattern. I already have the code in place to make the json valid except for the missing piece I just posted. I would say lets not think about json at all. Just think of the problem piece in general and how we can solve in unix.

Comment: Sorry I made an error in by first comment. Correction follows: Are you saying that if you have the line `"colour": "Red",`, followed by }, then to leave it alone? Possible answers: It must be fixed as well, It must not be fixed, it does not matter if it is fixed or not.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - any other pattern except "fruit" does not matter in my case. So, yes, leave it alone would be my answer.

Comment: Thankyou. As it does not matter, I would choose to fix it, as it will make the solution much simpler. Adding code to only fix lines containing the word fruit, will add complexity to the solution.

Comment: @Somy: It's still an x-y problem.  Why doesn't your other code fix the fruit issue?  That sounds like you need to fix your other code and/or find a better solution that works for all possibilities.

Comment: Sed is processing the file line by line, which will make it hard to find and replace newlines. But take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak ':begin;$!N;s/,\n}/\n}/g;tbegin;P;D' FILE
```

> `sed -i.bak` = creates a backup of the original file, then applies changes to the file
>
> `':begin;$!N;s/,\n}/\n}/g;tbegin;P;D'` = anything ending with *,* followed by *new line and }*. Remove the *,* on the previous line
>
> `FILE` = the file you want to make the change to

Answer (score 7):

What makes this a non-trivial problem is that the JSON format does not care about whitespace that does not occur inside keys or data.  Therefore,

```
{ "key": "data" }
```

is the same as

```
{ "key":
"data"
}
```

If you add the possibility of a "broken" JSON file, such as

```
{ "key":
"data", }
```

it becomes really difficult to properly parse the document with anything other than a JSON parser that knows how to relax the restrictions of the JSON format when parsing the data.

The Perl `JSON` module can do that, and also pretty-print the result:

```
$ cat file.json
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
}
```

```
$ perl -MJSON -e '@text=(<>);print to_json(from_json("@text", {relaxed=>1}), {pretty=>1})' file.json
{
   "fruit" : "Apple"
}
```

Here, we read in the whole text document into the array `@text`.  We then decode this while relaxing the parsing (this enables the JSON document to have commas before `}` and `]` and also to include `#` comments).  We then immediately encode the resulting Perl data structure into JSON again and print it.

Another example:

```
$ cat file.json
{
    "fruit": "Apple",   # a comment
    "stuff": [1, 2, 3,],
}
```

```
$ perl -MJSON -e '@text=(<>);print to_json(from_json("@text", {relaxed=>1}), {pretty=>1})' file.json
{
   "fruit" : "Apple",
   "stuff" : [
      1,
      2,
      3
   ]
}
```

Without pretty printing:

```
$ perl -MJSON -e '@text=(<>);print to_json(from_json("@text", {relaxed=>1}))' file.json
{"fruit":"Apple","stuff":[1,2,3]}
```

(no newline at the end of the output)

For really large documents, you would want to use the module's incremental parsing capability and write a proper script for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. I went ahead with the sed solution so did'nt try the one you shared. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) from a Node.js app or as a CLI utility (`npm install --global json5` or [Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/json5)):

```bash
json5 -s 2 file.json
```

The advantage of using JSON5 over the Perl-based solution from @Kusalananda is that object key ordering will be preserved.