# Extract value from broken JSON output in Shell

Tags: shell, json, yaml

Once I list the backup files from a server, It throws me the output as follows:

```
{
    "backupFiles": [
        "XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_14_12_10.gz",
        "XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_13_11_20.gz",
        "XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_13_15_11.gz",
    ],
    "total": 3
}
```

I stored the output to a variable.
Now how could I get the name of the files only :

```
XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_14_12_10.gz
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. Like, literally, any other question that asks "hey, I want to parse this non-regular language, e.g. JSON, YAML, XML, HTML, … using a string processor!" you'll probably get a helpful answer that reads "hi! don't do that. Just throw a tool that actually speaks JSON, YAML, XML, HTML, or whatever you're dealing with and don't worry about all the strange things that can and will go wrong with your approach, since you're relying on properties that your data might not have tomorrow". In your case, this seems JSON, and `jq` is relatively easy to use. Try it! You won't regret it :)

Comment: I'm adding the [tag:yaml] tag to this as the data is actually valid YAML.

Comment: Related - [Remove trailing commas from invalid json (to make it valid)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485004/100397)

Answer (score 3):

While this is indeed broken JSON, it's (at least as far as I can tell) valid YAML (which is mostly a superset of JSON, so wide it's hard to tell what's valid or not. I wish it wasn't.).

So, tools written for YAML can deal with it. I use [`yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), which is but a wrapper around `jq`, which converts YAML to valid JSON on the fly. So, all the things you can do with `jq`, you can do with `yq` as well. In your case

```bash
<yamldata.txt yq '.backupFiles []'
```

gives you

```
"XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_14_12_10.gz"
"XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_13_11_20.gz"
"XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_13_15_11.gz"
```

If you only wanted the first one,

```bash
<yamldata.txt yq '.backupFiles[0]'
```

prints

```
"XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_14_12_10.gz"
```

I find the quotes useful, usually, but to remove the `"`, use `--raw-output`.

Comment: Works also with [`yq` in golang](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (++)

Comment: @GillesQuénot ah nice!

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to go with your [json](/questions/tagged/json), is to use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), but here, `jq` will fails with error:

```
parse error: Expected another array element at line 6, column 5
```

I have another approach using [js](/questions/tagged/js) and [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

node<<EOF
let json = $(< file.json)
console.log(json["backupFiles"][0])
EOF
```

Or simply:

```
node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).backupFiles[0]' "$(cat file.json)"
```

if the `JSON` was well formed.

Output:

```
XYZ_Backup_2.0.0.0-417_2022_08_14_12_10.gz
```

Comment: love this! But would `#!/usr/bin/env node` have done the same? (honest question, don't know how node deals with shebang lines)

Comment: No, if you use pure `nodejs`, you have to deal with File Handle and import `fs` module. My way is a mix between shell and nodejs. `$(< file.json)` is a hack to avoid the need of opening the file with external modules

Comment: ah missed that one :)